# Angular2 observables vs. promises

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

I am currently developing a web-application which has to load a set of data from a SQL-Database (like some employees or workplans). Everytime when you get routed to a component and if you update the data it will be sent to the server and returns some kind of success or error message.

At the moment I use observables but they don't behave like I want. I subscribe to an observable, receive my data and unsubscribe (I am also not sure where to unsubscribe. In the onDestroy or in the `Complete` part of my sub?). But somehow it is still asynchronous as the code execution continues before receiving all the data which causes failures in my application.

**Here is an example of my implementation:**

Employee Component:

```
getEmployees(department: any){

this.employeesSub = this.employeeManagementService.getEmployees(department).subscribe(
          //Sucess
          data => {this.employees = data},
          //Error
          err => this.logger.error(err),
          //Complete
          () => {this.logger.log('done loading');
                }
    );
}
  ngOnInit(){

    this.selectedDepartment = this.ccs.getSelectedDepartment();
    //Does the same type of request as getEmployees()
    this.getDepartments();
    this.paramSub = this.route.params.subscribe(
        //Success    
        params => {    
            //doStuff
            }
        },
        //Error
        err => this.logger.error(err),
        //Complete
        () => {}
    );
}
  ngOnDestroy(){
      this.employeesSub.unsubscribe();
      this.paramSub.unsubscribe();
  }
```

Employee Service:

```
getEmployees(department: string): Observable<Employee[]>{
    let method = "getEmployees";
    let body = JSON.stringify({method, department});
    this.logger.log(body);
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.post(this.url, body, options)
                    .map((res:Response) =>{ 
                            this.logger.log(res.json());
                            return res.json();
                    }).catch(this.handleError);
}
```

I know this may have been asked often here. But I am really unsure about the difference even if I read more and more posts I won't get it.  Could someone take some time and help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unsubscribing is a bit redundant because the observable returned from `this._http.xxx()` closes after the first event, which causes the subscription to become cancelled anyway.

To ensure that on your side, you can also use `this._http.xxx().first().subscribe(...)`. This way the subscription is closed after the first event no matter how many events the sender intends to emit.

That code execution continues without waiting for a response is the nature of async execution and quite similar using promise or observable.

If you want code to be executed after data arrived you have to move that code into `subscribe(...)`, `map(...)` or some other observable operator.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. I changed my subscriptions and added the `.take(1)` to everyone of them. I have already tried to put the rest of my init code into the `complete` part of the first subscribed observable. It seems to work but I think it is a really ugly solution. Isn't there any other way?

Comment: I don't really understand the observable operators. I thought they are only for "small" operations with the returned result.

Comment: You can put any code into them. If you call another method from within the callback it's still small but the method could execute a huge amount of code. I'd say just don't worry about the amount of code executed in observable operators. To keep the browser responsible it's always a good idea to don't do unnecessary expensive work inside or outside of operators.

Comment: As example if I call the `getDepartments()` in the `onInit()` I just move my `onInit()` code which would come after the `getDepartments()` in a method and call it in the `.map` operator of my departments observable, right? But that seems a bit ugly to me as I move `onInit` code somewhere else.

Comment: Yes, that sounds reasonable.

Comment: But isn't that an ugly way of programming? And how should I name the method that it makes sense? Sorry for so much questions but thank you for helping me out everytime :)

Comment: Async execution has advantages (not threads, no race conditions) but it also has some disavantages. But that is how it works.

Comment: "the observable returned from this._http.xxx() closes after the first event" ? @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: @RafaelReyes that's the idea of `first()`

Comment: Ok, so on a single call that expects only one value per response, How "this.http.xxx()" knows when to close the http connection with the server? --instead of keep "open" waiting for possibles other values over the time as describes the Observable definition. (without using the first()) @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: The server closes the connection when it's done sending the response.

Answer (score 0):

Promices:
  Emits only a single value at time .
  Calls the services without then and catch.
  Cannot be cancelled. 
  Does not provide any operator.

Observable :
   Emits multiple values overva period of time. 
   It is not called until we subscribe to the observable 
   Provide the map,forEach,filter,reduce,retry and retry when. 
   They are function which is subscribe later on
   Lazy

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this article: https://scholarbasta.com/promises-vs-observables/

Promises are used when,

1. The event completes in one go.
2. The event only emits a single value,
3. You really do not need to unsubscribe to this event.

Use observables when:

1. You need to unsubscribe to this event,
2. Multiple streams are being emitted and you need to perform various operations on them.
3. Say you need to filter/ map some values. The Rxjs library is pretty powerful in that way.
4. There are multiple values from the same source.